# I want to pass the array to the template of bottle and display its contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, bottle

**environment**

・Python 3.6.0

・bottle 0.13-dev

・mod_wsgi-4.5.15

---

**Trying the following code on the web results in 500 errors**

> 500 Internal Server Error

---

app/wsgi

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(dirpath)
sys.path.append('../')
os.chdir(dirpath)
import bottle
import index
application = bottle.default_app()
```

---

index.py

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bottle import route, view

@route('/')
@view("index_template")
def index():
    html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
    internalLinks=[]
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        for link in bsObj.findAll("a"):
            if 'href' in links.attr:
                internalLinks.append(links.attr['href'])
    return dict(internalLinks=internalLinks)
```

---

views/index_template.tpl

```
{{internalLinks}}
```

---

**apache log**

```
[error]  mod_wsgi (pid=23613): Target WSGI script '/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[error]  mod_wsgi (pid=23613): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/app.wsgi'.
[error]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[error]    File "/app.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
[error]      import index
[error]    File "/index.py", line 11
[error]      for link in bsObj.findAll("a"):
[error]      ^
[error]  IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log reports an `IndentationError`, so there's something wrong the indentation in your code: specifically, the `for` loop is over-indented, the `for` statement should be at the same level as the `bsObj` assignment.

You also need to make your variable names consistent (`link`|`links`) and use the `attrs` attribute, not `attr`.  Fixed code below (untested).

```
@route('/')
@view("index_template")
def index():
    html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
    internalLinks=[]
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for link in bsObj.findAll("a"):
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            internalLinks.append(link.attrs['href'])
    return dict(internalLinks=internalLinks)
```